# Wxpython closing windows

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have two windows in my application and one of these windows has no frame for design purposes.

The frame with the window has the usual toolbar with the minimize, restore, maximize and close buttons.

Is there a way i can close the window with no frame, with the framed windows close button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You just need to save a reference to the 2nd frame. Something like this should suffice:

```
self.secondFrame = MySecondFrame()
```

Then in the first frame's close method, you can just do something like this:

```
self.secondFrame.Close()
```

However, I should note that creating a frame without the usual toolbar goes against most OS GUI guidelines and users will likely be irritated by that design decision.

**EDIT**: Yes, you can catch the event that occurs when the user presses the "X" button on the window via wx.EVT_CLOSE. When you do that, you need to call the main frame's Destroy() method instead of its Close method or you'll end up in an infinite loop since calling Close() fires EVT_CLOSE. You can still use Close() for the second frame though.

Comment: I don't have a close method. i'm talking about the X in the corner, it just comes with windows.

I'd also like to put an alert in that says, "Are you sure you want to close?"

Comment: I'm presuming it would be a little bit more low level.

Comment: I can use a File -> Exit.. and do that.

But is there a way to do it by just clicking the X?

Comment: Yes, see my modified answer

Comment: Thanks Mike, you are a legend my friend.

Comment: Took me 5 seconds to do it mike, you're a legend!